# row count and values in one select

Tags: mysql

I've got table structure with 2tables

First are teachers with IDs and second are students with IDs; Every student has only one teacher, so in student table there's column for teacher's ID.

Currenctly I'm using this select:

```
SELECT t.`id`, t.`name`, count(ti.`identificator`) as student_count FROM `teachers` t
LEFT JOIN `students` ti ON t.`id` = ti.`teacher_id`
GROUP BY t.`id`"
```

I'm getting result like this:

```
1 | Jack   | 22
2 | Daniel | 29
```

Is it possible to do in one select showing all of assigned students? Like this:

```
1 | Jack   | 22 | Student1
1 | Jack   | 22 | Student2
.
.
.
2 | Daniel | 29 | Student25
```

I hope my question is clear, i know i can do hat in two select, or in one and count with php, but I'm trying to make it from MySQL.

Thanks, guys...and ladies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get what you want, you need a subselect for the count:

```
SELECT
    t.`id`, 
    t.`name`, 
    student_count.`count`,
    s.`name`
FROM `teachers` t
LEFT JOIN `students` s ON t.`id` = s.`teacher_id`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ti.`teacher_id`, 
        count(*) as count 
    FROM `students` ti
    GROUP BY ti.`teacher_id`) student_count ON t.`id` = student_count.`teacher_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of column for students is `Studentname`

Maybe this could work

```
SELECT 
t.`id`, 
t.`name`, 
count(ti.`identificator`) as student_count,
ti.StudentName
FROM `teachers` t
LEFT JOIN `students` ti ON t.`id` = ti.`teacher_id`
GROUP BY t.`id`,t.`name`,ti.StudentName
```

Comment: See my query below, you have to have a subquery to get the full count.

Comment: @cdwaddell till now i tested it. It's working, marked your answer as right. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the student name as well in your query; assuming `name` is a column in student table

```
SELECT t.`id`, t.`name`, count(ti.`identificator`) as student_count, 
ti.name 
FROM `teachers` t
LEFT JOIN `students` ti ON t.`id` = ti.`teacher_id`
GROUP BY t.`id`"
```

Comment: I tried your solution before I asked, but it show only first student for every teacher as it is grouped by teacher's id...